# Cheat sheet for Visual Studio shortcuts with ids and descriptions

Tags: visual-studio-2015, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to modify Visual Studio 2015 keyboard shortcuts. All cheat sheets I can find, only include the shortcut and the description of what it does. This doesn't help *changing* the shortcut, because in Visual Studio's settings there is only id of the command, which are in this format:
ClassViewContextMenus.ClassViewProject.ApplicationInsights.OpenApplicationInsightsPortal

It's impossible to find anything from the list or to know what they mean!

Edit:
For example, I want to open file that is included in project. When I search "open", I get maybe couple hundred results, and if I'm patient enough, I can find edit.openfile, file.openfile, tools.open, view.open etc.
If I need to change many shortcuts, reading every single command in a list of hundreds and googling every one of them is not efficient at all.

Edit 2: I need to find a cheat sheet that links descriptions and ids.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2015

1. Go to **Tools** -> **Options**
2. Write the word `Keyboard` in the search area
3. Select the command that you want from the List
4. Select `Press Shortcut Key` field and press the keys that you want to change 
   the shortcut of the command

**NOTE** you can use the `Show command containing` field to filter the hundreds of the commands.

[image]

Comment: Like I said, I need to know the descriptions that match to ids.

Id list as such is very impractical to use: 1) there might be hundreds of items when you try to search for something, 2) you can't possibly be sure which one of the very similar items mean what you want to do.

Comment: @lll I updated me answer, you can filter the command you want by typing its name.

Comment: Like I said, the ids don't tell me anything because the ids and descriptions are not linked in any way!

Comment: @III what do you mean by 'description' ?

Comment: What the id means. For example, if I want to open an included file (#include "File.cpp"), and I search for "open", I get edit.openfile, file.openfile, tools.open, view.open etc., and if I need to repeat this process many times and google each command, it's not efficient.